# Calculate PES_packet_data_byte count when PES_packet_length == 0

Tags: protocols, mpeg2-ts

In `MPEG-TS` stream, in PES bitstream `PES_packet_length` can be 0 then PES `packet size` is determined by `payload_unit_start_indicator==1` of TS packet (First TS packet of next PES packet), is this right ?

Now when total size of PES packet is known `PES_packet_length` is unknown (0) how to calculate `stuffing_byte` count and `PES_packet_data_byte count` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PES_packet_length can be 0 is only true for video frames. Audio frames can not be of length 0. In this case, stuffing bytes are not allowed, and adaption field padding should be used instead. (AF size can be 0, if only one padding byte is needed)